# Why is the parallel version of my code slower than the serial one?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, google-colaboratory, python-multiprocessing, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to run a model multiple times. As a result it is time consuming. As a solution I try to make it parallel. However, it ends up to be slower. **Parallel is 40 seconds** while **serial is 34 seconds**.

```
# !pip install --target=$nb_path transformers
oracle = pipeline(model="deepset/roberta-base-squad2")
question = 'When did the first extension of the Athens Tram take place?'
print(data)
print("Data size is: ", len(data))


parallel = True

if parallel == False:
  counter = 0
  l = len(data)
  cr = []
  for words in data:
    counter+=1
    print(counter, " out of ", l)
    cr.append(oracle(question=question, context=words))
elif parallel == True:
  from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
  import multiprocessing

  no_CPU = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
  print("Number of cpu : ", no_CPU)
  l = len(data)


  def answer_question(data, no_CPU, sub_no):
    cr_process = []
    counter_process = 0
    for words in data:
      counter_process+=1
      l_data = len(data)
      # print("n is", no_CPU)
      # print("l is", l_data)
      print(counter_process, " out of ", l_data, "in subprocess number", sub_no)
      cr_process.append(oracle(question=question, context=words))
      # Q.put(cr_process)
    cr.append(cr_process)


  n = no_CPU      # number of subprocesses
  m = l//n        # number of data the n-1 first subprocesses will handle
  res = l % n     # number of extra data samples the last subprocesses has
  
  # print(m)
  # print(res)
  procs = []
  # instantiating process with arguments
  for x in range(n-1):
    # print(x*m)
    # print((x+1)*m)
    proc = Process(target=answer_question, args=(data[x*m:(x+1)*m],n, x+1,))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
  proc = Process(target=answer_question, args=(data[(n-1)*m:n*m+res],n,n,))

  procs.append(proc)
  proc.start()

  # complete the processes
  for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

A sample of the `data` variable can be found [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/272b15ed) (to not flood the question). Argument `parallel` controls the serial and the parallel version. So my question is, why does it happen and how do I make the parallel version faster? I use google colab so it has 2 CPU cores available , that's what `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` is saying at least.

Comment: Side note: `if x == False: ... elif x == True: ...` --> `if not x: ... else: ...`.

Comment: Synchronization, most likely. Multiprocess/multithread is effective only when the processes/threads work on independent data.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond yeah I understand know. I did not know that the pipeline was already parallel. Now it's obvious that parallel will be a bit slower in this case. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipeline is already running on multi-cpu even when run as one process. The code of transformers are optimized to run on multi-cpu.
when on top of that you are creating multiple process, you are loosing some time for building the processes and switching between them.

To verify this, on the so-called "single process" version look at your cpu utilizations, you should already see all are at max, so creating extra parallel processes are not going to save you some time,

Comment: So, despite the fact that I call the pipeline multiple times, via a for-loop, it's still parallel? That's very interesting thank you for your time.

Comment: @Skapis9999 Your python function may be serial, however the underlying C/C++ code it is calling is performing a multi-processes calculation that is using all of your cores.

Comment: you are very welcome, the point is that your python code (here pipeline either if it is using pytorch or tf or any ml tools) are written in C/C++ and highly optimized to run on all the resources you have (unless you have installed or done somehting wrong).